# How to a plot a line for ax+by-c in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, linear-programming

The title basically says it all. I'm doing an assignment and need to include a plot of my scatter and the line generated by `linprog()`.

I ran `linprog()` and got the values:

```
1.0000
1.0000
16.5000
12.5000
```

for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `f`, respectively. The equation for my line is:

```
ax + by - c = 0
```

I know it's a simple question, but I've been looking all night for an answer and nothing has presented itself. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `x` to your range of interest, solve for `y` and plug `x` in.

```
x = 0:0.01:10;
y = (-a*x + c)/b;
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: But what if `b` is 0?

Comment: y formula is wrong, it should be y = -(a*x+c) / b
and if b = 0 then the line is a x + c = 0 means that it is a straight line with no slope.
y = ones(1,length(x)) * c/a
So you need to plot(x, y)